# How to find a basis for a set of functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

The following set $W$ is a subspace of $V=P_2$:

$W=\{p(x) ∈ P_2|p(1)=0 ∈ R\}.$

Find a basis of $W.$ What is $\dim(W)?$

I believe that $\dim(W)$ is $3$ and I know that $W$ contains functions like $p(x)=x-1$ or $p(x)=x^2-1.$ But I don't understand how to find a basis. Do I just take $3$ random functions that lie in $W?$

Comment: Just picking the correct number of "random" elements will _probably_ give you a basis, and this goes for any finite-dimensional vector space with an infinite number of vectors in it. However, it is not guaranteed, and must be checked for linear independence.

Comment: So if I take 3 random elements in W that are linearly independent, they give me a basis?

Comment: More or less, yes. Any linearly independent set of vectors is a basis for the vector space that they span.

Comment: If I understood correctly: $P_2$ is the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Alright thanks so much :)

Comment: There are some times a standard basis, for instance in $P_2$ it would be $\{1, x, x^2\}$ and in $\Bbb R^3$ it would be $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. But most of the time you are free to choose other bases if you feel like it.

Answer (score 2):

I am supposing that P2 is polynomial of degree 2. 
Then let $P(x)=(ax^2+bx+c)\in V$. For it to be in W, $P(1)=0$ => $a+b+c=0$ 
Now, $P(x)=ax^2+bx-a-b$ => $P(x)=a(x^2-1)+b(x-1)$
Hence, W consists of all polynomials of the form $a(x^2-1)+b(x-1)$. Hence, it has dimension 2 and $x^2-1$ and $x-1$ are basis functions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\{x-1, x^2-1\} \subseteq W$. Furthermore, $\{x - 1, x^2 - 1\}$ is linearly independent, since $x - 1$ is a polynomial of degree $1$, and $x^2 - 1$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, so they cannot be proportional.

Since $\dim P_2 = 3$, we must have $\dim W \leq 2$ because clearly $W \ne P_2$. But, we have found a linearly independent set $\{x-1, x^2-1\}$ in W, so $\dim W \geq 2$.

Hence, $\dim W = 2$, and $\{x-1, x^2-1\}$ is a basis for $W$ (it is a linearly independent set in $W$ with cardinality equal to $\dim W$).